# Can't get access to Views by DataBinding or Android Extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, data-binding, android-view

I can't change value of Views by DataBinding or by Android Extensions, but it works by 'traditional way' (findViewById). Also, it throws NPE when I try by Android Extensions' way without safe call operator.

**HourlyFragment.kt**

```
class HourlyFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentHourlyBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false
    )

    // doesn't work
    //binding.tvHourly.text = "HOURLY!"

    val tvHourly : TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hourly)
    tvHourly.setText("HOURLY!!")

    // doesn't work, without safe call operator throws NullPointerException
    //tv_hourly?.text = "HOURLY!!!"

    return rootView
}
```

}

**fragment_hourly.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.HourlyFragment">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hourly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hourly fragment" />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are inflating your views twice and that's causing all the issues I believe, so instead just inflate your views once and see if it solves your issue

Try the following

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

 // var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false
    )

    binding.tvHourly.text = "HOURLY!"

   // val tvHourly : TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hourly)
    tvHourly.setText("HOURLY!!")

   

    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why your data binding doesn't work:**

You are manually inflating with the line

```
var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false)
```

but then you use data binding to inflate another copy of this hierarchy in the next line of code. You then return the first layout from `onCreateView`, throwing away your second inflated data binding layout. You changed the text of the view in the data binding layout that you then threw away.

**Why your Android Extensions doesn't work:**

You can't use the synthetic view references before `onCreateView()` returns, because the Fragment still doesn't have any view attached to it for the synthetic property to use to find the child view.

You should be modifying view content in `onViewCreated()` instead.

By the way, Android Extensions is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

In a more concise and more readable way:

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentHourlyBinding

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, 
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = FragmentHourlyBinding.inflate(
        inflater, container, false
    ).apply {
        tvHourly.text = "HOURLY!"
    }

    return binding.root
}
```